# Python, check how much of a string is in uppercase?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have a text, and I want to know if all or a percent bigger than 50% is in uppercase.

> DOFLAMINGO WITH TOUCH SCREEN lorem ipsum

I try to use regex(found here a solution):

```
rx = re.compile(r"^([A-Z ':]+$)", re.M)
upp = rx.findall(string)
```

But this finds all caps, i don't know if all or more than 50 percent(this includes all) is uppercase ?

I want to number only letters (so no numbers,spaces, new lines etc)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) and [`str.isalpha`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) to clean out non-alphabetic chars and [`str.isupper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper) to count uppercase chars and calculate the ratio:

```
s = 'DOFLAMINGO WITH TOUCH SCREEN lorem ipsum'

alph = list(filter(str.isalpha, s))  # ['D', ..., 'O', 'W', ..., 'N', 'l', 'o', ...]
sum(map(str.isupper, alph)) / len(alph)
# 0.7142857142857143
```

Also see the docs on [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) and [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) which you might find yourself using regularly. Moreover, this uses the fact that [`bool` is a subclass of `int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool) and is cast appropriately for the summation which might be too implicit for the taste of some.

Answer (score 5):

Regex seems overkill here. You can use `sum` with a generator expression:

```
x = 'DOFLAMINGO WITH TOUCH SCREEN lorem ipsum'

x_chars = ''.join(x.split())  # remove all whitespace
x_upper = sum(i.isupper() for i in x_chars) > (len(x_chars) / 2)
```

Or functionally via `map`:

```
x_upper = sum(map(str.isupper, x_chars)) > (len(x_chars) / 2)
```

Alternatively, via `statistics.mean`:

```
from statistics import mean

x_upper = mean(i.isupper() for i in s if not i.isspace()) > 0.5
```

Comment: Or you could use: `statistics.mean(ch.isupper() for ch in s if not ch.isspace())`

Comment: @JonClements, Yep, good point, but a *little* messier I think because of the `if` condition.

Comment: Well, since you're iterating character by character anyway to do the isupper check, I think it's a bit messier to do `''.join(x.split())` to create a new string to iterate over :)

Comment: The map method is not correct, and you should change str.upper to str.isupper.

Comment: @Adam75752, changed to `isupper`, I don't see why `map` method doesn't work here.

Answer (score 2):

Generic solution that works with any boolean function and iterable (see below for version that only looks at `str.isalpha()`):

```
def percentage(data, boolfunc):
    """Returns how many % of the 'data' returns 'True' for the given boolfunc."""
    return (sum(1 for x in data if boolfunc(x)) / len(data))*100

text = "DOFLAMINGO WITH TOUCH SCREEN lorem ipsum"

print( percentage( text, str.isupper ))
print( percentage( text, str.islower ))
print( percentage( text, str.isdigit ))
print( percentage( text, lambda x: x == " " ))
```

Output:

```
62.5  # isupper
25.0  # islower
0.0   # isdigit
12.5  # lambda for spaces
```

---

even better is schwobaseggl's

```
return sum(map(boolfunc,data)) / len(data)*100
```

because it does not need to persist a list but instead uses a generator.

---

Edit: 2nd version that only uses str.isalpha characters and allows multiple boolfuncs:

```
def percentage2(data, *boolfuncs):
    """Returns how many % of the 'data' returns 'True' for all given boolfuncs.

    Only uses str.isalpha() characters and ignores all others."""
    count = sum(1 for c in data if c.isalpha())
    return sum(1 for x in data if all(f(x) for f in boolfuncs)) / count * 100

text = "DOFLAMINGO WITH TOUCH SCREEN lorem ipsum"

print( percentage2( text, str.isupper, str.isalpha ))
print( percentage2( text, str.islower, str.isalpha ))
```

Output:

```
71.42857142857143
28.57142857142857
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expressions, this is one way you can do it  (given that `s` is the string in question):

```
upper = re.findall(r'[A-Z]', s)
lower = re.findall(r'[a-z]', s)
percentage = ( len(upper) / (len(upper) + len(lower)) ) * 100
```

It finds the lista of both uppercase and lowercase characters and gets the percentage using their lengths.

Comment: `( len(upper) / len(upper) + len(lower) )` == 1 + len(lower)

Comment: @Patrick Artner, I missed a pair of parenthesis. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
f = sum(map(lambda c: c.isupper(), f)) / len(f)
(sum(map(lambda c: c.isupper(), f)) / len(f)) > .50
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work.

```
string = 'DOFLAMINGO WITH TOUCH SCREEN lorem ipsum'
rx = re.sub('[^A-Z]', '', string)
print(len(rx)/len(string))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's short and does the job:

```
text = "DOFLAMINGO WITH TOUCH SCREEN lorem ipsum"
print("Percent in Capital Letters:", sum(1 for c in text if c.isupper())/len(text)*100)
# Percent in Capital Letters: 62.5
```